# PlayWright Azure Pipeline Error: browsertype.launch: executable doesn't exist at /home/vsts/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-965416/chrome-linux/chrome

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, playwright, azure-pipelines-yaml, playwright-java

When I try to execute playwright scripts in Azure pipeline using YML file, I am getting the below error:

browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at /home/vsts/.cache/ms-playwright/chromium-965416/chrome-linux/chrome
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
║                                                                         ║
║     npx playwright install                                              ║
║                                                                         ║
║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║    ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Context Used in YML file:

pool:
vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'

container: mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:focal

steps:

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
  versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: |
  npm install --registry https://registry.npmjs.org --no-fund playwright
  npx playwright install
  npm test
  displayName: 'npm install and test'

Dependencies Used:

"devDependencies": {
"@playwright/test": "^1.18.1",
"jest": "27.5.1",
"mocha": "^9.2.1",
"playwright": "^1.18.1"
}

Comment: Did you run `npx playwright install` to fix it?

Comment: Yeah, I use npx playwright install to install the browsers

Answer (score 2):

After changing the pool: vmImage from 'ubuntu-20.04' to 'windows-2019' and

Node js versionSpec from '16.x' to '17.x' the pipeline error gone

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to pin your Docker image to a specific Playwright version:

`docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/playwright:v1.20.0-focal`

Also you don't need to have `playwright` or `jest` installed, `@playwright/test` is enough. After these changes it should work!

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue as well

Two solutions for fixing this:

This in your pipeline.yml file:

```
- variables: 
  clientAppPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\client'
  backOfficeAppPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\backoffice'

- script: npx playwright install
  displayName: 'npm i playwright'
  workingDirectory: $(clientAppPath)
```

or check that playwright (not playwright/test) is in your dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json. If not then run this in the same folder as your package.json file.

```
npx playwright install
```

Comment: what is the value of `clientAppPath`?

Comment: Forgot about that one. Its a set variable
/client has its own package.json which includes playwright and so on.
Ive updated the answer